# Write applescript that changes focus to another desktop monitor?

Tags: applescript

Right now I have 3 external monitors hooked up to a MacBook Pro. What would the AppleScript be for changing which monitor desktop has the focus.

To do this manually, you have to move your cursor to the monitor and click. I'm trying to write an applescript to pair with a keyboard shortcut to not have to do this

```
on changeDesktopFocus(desktop_to_focus)

// TODO

end changeDesktopFocus
```

Comment: Also curious about this. I am using Keyboard Maestro and can somewhat achieve this by positioning the cursor relative to the main display. It's really not ideal but it's the best I've got. I believe you can position the mouse with AppleScript but it looks like it's not that straightforward.

Comment: Focus on mac only needs the mouse position, not a click FWIW.